# Failed to start system service on centos with ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I created a system service called cooltoo_storage on centos. I am able to start/stop/restart the service by running the command "service cooltoo_storage start/stop/restart". Now I want to configure it on ansible playbook. Below is my config for starting this service.

```
- name: start cooltoo_storage service
  sudo: yes
  service:
  name: cooltoo_storage
  state: started
```

After running the ansible-playbook, I got below error

```
msg: Job for cooltoo_storage.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cooltoo_storage.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Below is the command output of "systemctl status cooltoo_storage.service",

```
● cooltoo_storage.service - LSB: cooltoo storage provider
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cooltoo_storage)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-05-02 11:39:07 CST; 1min 5s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 26661 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cooltoo_storage start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

 May 02 11:39:07 Cool-Too systemd[1]: Starting LSB: cooltoo storage provider...
May 02 11:39:07 Cool-Too systemd[26661]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.d/init.d/cooltoo_storage: Exec format error
May 02 11:39:07 Cool-Too systemd[1]: cooltoo_storage.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
May 02 11:39:07 Cool-Too systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: cooltoo storage provider.
May 02 11:39:07 Cool-Too systemd[1]: Unit cooltoo_storage.service entered failed state.
May 02 11:39:07 Cool-Too systemd[1]: cooltoo_storage.service failed.
```

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is irrelevant to `Ansible`.

Your service `cooltoo_storage` failed to start. Just make sure it works:

```
sudo systemctl restart cooltoo_storage.service
sudo systemctl status cooltoo_storage.service
```

And if not - fix it. Probably `cooltoo_storage` custom written service. Start investigating from checking out startup config for this specific service:

```sh
systemctl cat cooltoo_storage.service
```

and contents of: `/etc/rc.d/init.d/cooltoo_storage`